# http_build_query but replace & with ; in PHP?

Tags: php

`http_build_query($array)` will convert array to the format of `a=1&b=2`,

But how to make it convert to the format of `a=1;b=2`?

Is there a native function there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third parameter to [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) is the separator; call it with `http_build_query($array, "", ";")` to get what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the info. A quick related question, what is the opposite function that is equivalent to `parse_str` but delimits with ; instead of &

Comment: I don't know that there is one, short of `explode`ing `$_GET` on `;`.

Answer (score 4):

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) can do that as of PHP 5.1.2. For example:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data, '', ';');
```

As you can see the third parameter is the `arg_separator` and can be any string you like.

Output from the above example would be:

```
foo=bar;baz=boom;cow=milk;php=hypertext+processor
```